# How do I make zombies in my topdown 2d game follow the player without getting stuck in areas/corners of the map?

Tags: c#

I am making a topdown 2d zombie game in Unity 5.6.1f1 and I am trying to have the zombies follow the player using a simple script in C#.It works, however the problem comes when the player goes to certain parts of the map and the zombies follow, and they end up getting stuck running into the corners/edges of walls blindly following the player. Is there a way to fix this, so they can perhaps travel up the walls and get to the player instead of waiting for the player to make their way back to them (The zombies are always moving). In the picture I linked, the zombies follow a straight path(red arrow),i would like for them to kind of "rubberband" around walls/objects so they dont get stuck like in the blue arrow.  Here is the script I am using for the zombies. I would really prefer to keep it simple and not use any pathfinding solutions,thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LubiN.jpg

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Transform player;
    void FixedUpdate () {

    float z =Mathf.Atan2((player.transform.position.y - transform.position.y),(player.transform.position.x - 
        transform.position.x)) *
            Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, z);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * speed );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Well you do need to check whether where they are moving to is indeed a valid option and do something else if they can't move in the desired direction - which already qualifies as a very simple form of pathfinding

Comment: A common pathfinding algorithm is `A*` (A-Star)

Comment: In fact I'm unsure what kind of answer you are expecting - you know what your code doesn't do correctly and you know what you want to achieve - so why don't you just write the code for it?

Comment: This is a well established problem in programming (most notably game development). Pathfinding algorithms are specifically made to tackle this problem. However, this depends on many things: are you using hex tiles or square tiles, which tiles can be traversed and which cannot (e.g; ghosts can go through walls but zombies cannot), is there a consideration for walk speed (slow straight line vs faster zigzag), and most notably a balance between an acceptable result **while also** having acceptable calculation performance. You need to read up on this and find an algorithm that works for you.

Comment: this is my first game and this is a script i am using, i did not write it, i just made a few tweaks to it. I am pretty inexperienced so I do not know what code I have to write in order to do what I want. I was hoping someone could provide some code.

Comment: We don't provide code on SO. We fix code that has flaws. This is to prevent people from using SO as their personal code writing service. I'm not accusing you of doing that; I'm explaining why this global rule is instituted for all SO questions.

Comment: Ok well, can i adress this issue simply by adding more code to the script or would it involve making some changes in unity itself.

Comment: Any decent path finding algorithm should work. Just make the player the target location and update the path when the player moves. A* is probably your best bet.But you are running into AI programming which is a big endeavor.

Comment: Note that Unity offers a pathfinding solution which may be what you want to use instead of writing your own - check the manual to see if it fits your use-case: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you don't really know how to code, so you should probably lookup at Unity builtin pathfinding system, it's working flawlessly and is easy to setup,

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation
Here you have the overview and lots of links about navigation, and more precisely about AI Navigation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1lZyKI384Y
this video and this series show the pathfinding of zombies in 3D but you should be able to tweak it to have it in 2D

Comment: Link answers are not preferred on StackOverflow as the URLs can change over time or become inaccessible. Secondly, I stopped reading after `From my understanding, you don't really know how to code` because that is just plain dismissive and competely misses the point that your answer should point out the flaw in OP's code or approach, rather than point out OP's flaws.

Comment: Ok, Not wanting to start a debate there, but did you even read what the OP wrote ?

"this is my first game and this is a script i am using, i did not write it, i just made a few tweaks to it. I am pretty inexperienced so I do not know what code I have to write in order to do what I want. I was hoping someone could provide some code."

this is not dismissive at all, from my understanding, and since the OP want someone that can provide him code i can suppose he don't know how to code, and that's fine, i'm not poiting any flaws in his code for the sole reason that he didn't write this code

Comment: Second, his code is perfectly fine, it's just not doing what we want, to actually match the behaviour he wish, he should reprogram one of the pathfinding algorithm which are rather complex to implement, so i'm pointing him over a well designed solution directly built in Unity so that he don't have to code a lot, also, these links contains way too much informations (that are all needed) for me to synthesise them here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for you:

**Pathfinding:**
Use a path finding system like A* or Dijkstra's. To do this you probably need some underlying map going on, but there are some good path finding assets on the asset store.

**Line of Sight:**
In this solution, why not turn a programming problem into a game mechanic? Zombies aren't very smart, and if they lose sight of you they might get confused. For each zombie, if it has a line of sight directly towards the player, they charge at the player. When they lose sight of the player, the zombie gets a marker where they last saw the player. One way to implement this would be to update the target location to the player every frame if the zombie can see the player. If it can't see the player, the marker won't move.

**Player path (smell):**
Once again lets try to make this into a neat mechanic. Maybe keep a track of the path the player has taken recently, if the zombies can't see you, they will move towards the closest path point, each path points then leads to another until the zombies can see the player again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like your suggestions, but the smell suggestion is somewhat nonsensical. A "smell path" means that you can only be followed when the zombie has already come across your smell. The zombie cannot magically know where the nearest smell path is. It can only sense the smell **when it crosses the smell path**. Consider it like an invisible (but tangible) rope that the player carries behind them. The zombie can only follow the rope when he has touched (smelled) it.

Comment: I just tried to turn the problem into a neat little game mechanic. If you want to flesh out the mechanic a bit more to make sure it makes sense, then you would have to put in a little more work, which is where your suggestion comes in.